# What are the recommended BEST CASE hardware requirements for TFS 2010

Tags: hardware, tfs

i have installed TFS 2010 in a 2 server setup with an App Tier server and a SQL Server and am not 100% happy with the performance.

Both are running in VM's on SAN disks and have been given the following virtual hardware each:

- Windows 2008 R2
- 1 CPU @ 2.8Ghz
- 2gb RAM

what should i lift - neither machine is hammered but both do go up to 80% when people are doing things on them - should i add another CPU to each - usually this is now required in a VMWARE setup but i don't know if TFS 2010 takes advantage of an extra core???

thank you in advance :-)

Comment: SQL Server will, for sure, use the additional core so having an extra core on each might help but having one on the SQL Server VM will be a good start.

Comment: I would see if the RAM is peaking, and increase it if it is.

Comment: If both tiers are running in a VM, why did you split it?  The reality is all you've done is double the cost of the software with no benefit.

Comment: BTW, how many users are you trying to support?

Comment: Did you install TFS 64 or 32?

Comment: I agree with Chris, a VM running 2 CPU's and 4GB of RAM should support 250 user no bother

Comment: there are 2 cpus in the front end server and this has sped things up a lot. It was the front end that was peaking strangely. SQL server is still only on one core and everything is speedy again. I installed on two VM's because we have MSDN for licensing and i prefer having a seperation of concerns between app and sql as i'm about to import 150+ projects from source safe so this is going to be a big installation. There is only going to be 30 users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that i am more having issues with sharepoint going cold on non-peak use projects.

By installing an IIS app warmer, i solved all my problems:

http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2010/05/06/keep-your-aspnet-websites-warm-and-fast-247

I am running my app server with 2 virtual cores and 2gb of RAM and it's booming

I have the database server using 2gb RAM and a single core